# Determine whether S is a subspace of P3. Vector space of all real polynomials.

Tags: polynomials, vector-spaces

[image]

ATTEMPT:
Have given a small attempt just really confused on how to approach.
So I got the general equation of $p(x)= a + bx +cx^2 +dx^3$.

So we find the derivative? and find the values of $a,b,c,d$? 
How do I find the polynomials? like the 2nd equation?

My working is just all over the place and then I know what to do next with the addition and scalar multiplication steps. Just not sure on preliminary steps.

Comment: (A) To find the elements of S, you need to apply the property p(1) = 0, and p'(1) = 0 in your general polynomial equation. This will give you two relations in the coefficients that *must* be satisfied for all elements of S. Restricted to these coefficient relations and knowing that S is a subset of a vector space, what properties must it satisfy in order to be a subspace?

Comment: Im just on my way to work now. But off top of my head. The expressions must equal zero, which proves that s and p is an element of P3. If so then the set of solutions is closed under addition and scalar multiplication and also a subspace of P3. Still really confused though. I know how to do the addition and scalar steps can you just set me up on the preliminary steps if possible?

Answer (score 3):

Any element of the vector space $P_3$ is of the form,

$p(x)= a + bx +cx^2 +dx^3$

Substituting x = 1, we get,

$p(1)= a + b.1 + c.1^2 +d.1^3$

$\implies a + b + c + d = 0$

For p'(1), we have after differentiating,

$p'(x)= b + 2cx +3dx^2$

$p'(1)= b + 2c.1 +3d.1^2 = 0 $

$\implies b + 2c +3d = 0$

So, you know every element of S follows these two relations. Now assume two vectors $u, v$ of S with real coefficients
$u = a_1 + b_1 x + c_1 x^2 + d_1 x^3$ and $v = a_2 + b_2 x + c_2 x^2 + d_2 x^3$
and try to prove whether or not it is a subspace by testing whether S is closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication, i.e. For any vector $r$ in $P_3$, such that

$r=v+u={(a_1+a_2)} + {(b_1+b_2)}x + {(c_1+c_2)}x^2 + {(d_1+d_2)}x^3$

We can find constants $a_3, b_3, c_3, d_3$ in $R$ such that $a_3 = a_1 +a_2$ and so on. That means,

$r=a_3+b_3x+c_3x^2+d_3x^3$

Since we know that both $a_1+b_1+c_1+d_1=0$ and $a_2+b_2+c_2+d_2=0$, we can infer that $a_3+b_3+c_3+d=0$ and similarly that $b_3+2c_3+3d_3=0$. This means that the vector $r$ lies in the subset $S$, and hence $S$ is closed under vector addition.
Using similar arguments, we see that S is also closed under scalar multiplication, and so, $S$ is a subspace of $P_3$.

For part (B): you need to verify whether the two coefficient conditions are satisfied for $q(x)$, that is,

$a+b+c+d = 0 + 1 + (-2) + 1 = 0$

and

$b+2c+3d = 1 + 2(-2)+3(1) = 0$

which implies $q(x)$ is an element of $S$.

Comment: thanks im attempting this but its different from Jason. Would u be able to show me a bit more working.Still confused sorry

Comment: Elaborated the answer a little more.

Answer (score 2):

Part A: You have to check $S$ against the definition of a subspace.

That means:

(1) Is the zero vector in $S$?

(2) For any two vectors $p$ and $q$ in $S$, is their sum in $S$?

(3) For any vector $p$ in $S$, is $cp$ in $S$ for any scalar $c$?

$S$ is a subspace if and only if all of these are true.

For (1), the zero vector in the vector space as a whole is the zero polynomial, call it $z$. Clearly $z(1) = 0$ and $z^\prime(1) = 0$, so $z\in S$.

For (2), let $p$ and $q$ be any polynomials in $S$. Let $r = p + q$ as polynomials. Then $r(1) = p(1) + q(1)$. But by assumption, $p(1) = 0$ and $q(1) = 0$. So we have $r(1) = 0 + 0 = 0$.

Likewise, because $(f+g)^\prime = f^\prime + g^\prime$ in general, we have  $r^\prime(1) = p^\prime(1) + q^\prime(1)$. By assumption, this is $0 + 0 = 0$.

Therefore because $r(1) = 0$ and $r^\prime(1) = 0$, $r$ is in $S$.

Now for (3), let $p$ be any polynomial in $S$. I'm assuming the scalars are the real numbers. Then for any real number $c$, $cp$ is a polynomial, call it $w$. So we have $w(1) = cp(1)$. But by assumption, $p(1) = 0$ and so $w(1) = 0$. Likewise, because derivatives obey $(cf)^\prime = c\cdot f^\prime$ in general, we have $w^\prime(1)=cp^\prime(1)$. But by assumption $p^\prime(1) = 0$. So we have $w^\prime = c \cdot 0 = 0$.

Therefore because $w(1) = 0$ and $w^\prime = 0$, $w$ is in $S$.

Conclusion: since the zero vector is in $S$, and sums of vectors in $S$ are in $S$, and scalar multiples of $S$ are in $S$, therefore $S$ is a subspace.

Part B: See if $q(1) = 0$ and see if $q^\prime(1) = 0$.

Follow-up question: What if $S$ had been defined as the set of all polynomials of degree at most 3 satisfying $p(1) = 5$ and $p^\prime(1) = 5$?

Comment: I have just said the same thing to "Infinitum" above... Infinitum.  
Im just on my way to work now. But off top of my head. The expressions must equal zero, which proves that s and p is an element of P3. If so then the set of solutions is closed under addition and scalar multiplication and also a subspace of P3. Still really confused though. I know how to do the addition and scalar steps can you just set me up on the preliminary steps if possible?

Comment: Um yes zero vector is in S, yeah there full sum is in S. not sure about 3 and the rest. As I said just at work but will have look tomorrow. Thanks Jason

Comment: I will add some detail above.

Comment: Sorry thanks for the help but still so confused dont we have to do Two elements of S p1 and p2 then expand and add both, and  then after that scalar?

Comment: Here is what I was thinking. Suppose $p$ and $q$ are any polynomials whatsoever. Does it not follow that $p+q$ evaluated at 1 is equal to $p(1) + q(1)$? And does it not follow that the derivative of $p + q$ evaluated at 1 is $p^\prime(1) + q^\prime(1)$? And likewise for scalar multiples? So I am not seeing why we have to work with coefficients in any detail. (Remember we get to assume that $p(1) = q(1) = p^\prime(1) = q^\prime(1) = 0$.) I don't know why @Infinitum is getting into the details of the coefficients. Perhaps it is I who am missing something however.

Comment: Thanks ill give it a go a guess. Was just confused now so hoping for whole product. thanks for pointers jason

Comment: I just fleshed out the reply further. I think it is complete enough now to where if there is any single step that is causing you trouble, feel free to ask a question about it.

Comment: @JasonZimba You are right. There is no need to use the coefficients, of course, as you can prove both by just using the properties of polynomial derivatives, as you have. I just find it easier and satisfying to know what kind of element S will contain, so that operations are more obvious. That's probably just me, I guess.

Comment: @Infinitum That makes sense, appreciate the reply. Wanted to be sure I wasn't having a blind spot.